# how do I automatically execute a query that returns insert statements?

Tags: sql-server

I wrote the following query in order to move some data to a joinTable:

```
SELECT 'insert into dbo.person_parks (person_id, parks_id) values
('+ cast([id] as nvarchar) +',' + [parks_id] + ');'
FROM [dbo].[person] where parks_id is not null
```

Now this works fine as it displays the correct insert queries which I then take and execute on a separate query window, but how do I make it so they are executed/inserted automatically instead of being only displayed as a dataset?

Sorry this may be super obvious and easy but I'm not that experienced in SQL-Server, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Utilize execute sp_executesql(). http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.person_parks (person_id, parks_id)
SELECT CAST([id] as nvarchar), [parks_id]
FROM [dbo].[person] 
WHERE parks_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be kinda curious to see why you would do this in the first place and how the code gets called.  You could do insert and use an OUTPUT clause to show what was done instead.  Beware of sql injection when doing dynamic sql (doesn't look like it would be an issue here).

Comment: part of maintenance to add a many-to-many relation without modifying the other 2 tables really. Nothing dynamic, just a one-time thing hehe.